# moxa nport 5200x integration on linux

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port, modbus, pymodbus

I'm trying to use pymodbus over the nport to read some values of interest.
The code functions perfectly well on a windows machine in the same network but breaks in the connection phase on the linux server. (the nport is visible to the linux machine and the latest moxa drivers installed correctly as far as i can tell)

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient
client = ModbusSerialClient(
        method="rtu",
        port="X") 
print(client.connect)
```

where X the set up port through the moxa tool on the windows machine (usually COM10 for me)
and on the linux machine its supposed to be /dev/ttyr00 set up by the moxa driver if the documentation and console output is to be trusted (the ttyr00 port actually appears after mapping the moxa device).
pymodbus returns false on the connection attemp however (for linux only).

The linux machine is ubuntu 20.04.4 lts run in a container under proxmox.

I've also attempted to use the node-serial-modbus for that purpouse, there however I get the permission denied to the ttyr00 port. (everthing is run as root for my convinience for now and while I know of https://discourse.nodered.org/t/error-permission-denied-cannot-open-dev-ttyr0/25148/2 , my troubles are sadly not solvable that way).

Any insight or ideas would be greatly apreciated.

Edit: As an additional note the install procedure is described and handled by a script attached to the driver package (on linux). I went entirely with that.
Also the port permissions are: crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 33, 0 Aug 16 08:58 /dev/ttyr00
though here I have reduced them to lower ones, yet after reboot of the vm they go back to those.

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to use the Real TTY drivers; these units can act as a Modbus TCP server which you will probably find easier to work with overall (no drivers to install/configure - see "TCP Server Mode" in the manual). If you really want to use the virtual com port then please provide details as to how you installed the driver and let us know the permissions on the port (e.g. `ls -al /dev/ttyr00`).

Comment: I went along the README file attached to the drivers (for linux kernel version 5.x). I have never gotten the n-port to work in the non REALCOM mode unfortunately, having had expierience with just a few in a slightly different setting. 
the port permissions are as follows:
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 33, 0 Aug 16 08:58 /dev/ttyr00
though i did try to change them to lower ones just in case before (they reset after reboot of the vm)

Comment: For future reference, I went along the investigation route and found that it is fiesible to set up the nport in the suggested TCP server mode. then the tcp requests set to it were finally understood and worked in linux as well. (using the TCP client from the pymodbus library for a change).
the function of the port has to be set to TCP server (in the settings webpage it provides) the structure on the serial side has to be defined there as well, after that it translates stuff correctly. I would have liked to know why the realtime port approach fails but for now, at least there exists a solution

Comment: Permissions are set when the device is created (from memory changing these requires changes in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`). I don't think these drivers get a lot of love (the latest readme say its tested on "Ubuntu 18.10 x64" which went EOL in 2019). I have got this working in the past but don't currently have a unit available to test (they are all out in the field running in Modbus TCP server mode :-) ).